# gremlin query - how to use select in has

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

testing data as below:

```
g.addV('A').property('name','n').property('tag','key1');
g.addV('B').property('n','123');
g.addV('A').property('name','m').property('tag','key2');
g.addV('B').property('m','321')
g.V().hasLabel('A').addE('e').to(g.V().hasLabel('B'));
```

Given 'key1' and '123', how do I get the 1st B vertex?
I have tried below query, it does not work
`g.V().hasLabel('B').as('B').inE('e').outV().has('tag','key1').as('A').select('B').has(select('A').values('name'),'123')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a slightly different approach and replace `has` with a `where` step. It is confusing that the `has` step seems as if it should be able to accept an arbitrary traversal and yield its value. In fact all that happens is that if a traversal inside a `has` yields any result it is treated as "true".

```
gremlin>  g.V().hasLabel('A').
......1>        has('tag','key1').as('A').
......2>        out('e').
......3>        where(valueMap().select(select('A').values('name')).unfold().is('123')).     
......4>        valueMap(true)

==>[id:60872,label:B,n:[123]]
```

Comment: thanks Kelvin, it works! I thought I need to use 'where', but just don't know how exactly it should be, nice.

Answer (score -1):

```
g.V().has('A', 'tag', 'key1').
  out('e').
  has('B', 'n', '123')
```

The first line filters by the label "A" and the property "tag" == "key1".
The second line makes the Gremlin go out along the "e" edge. And it will land on the adjacent vertex.
The third line filters by the label "B" and the property "n" == "123"

Comment: you are assuming there is a property 'n' in B, that is not true, it could be anything.